# SQLite: How do I set up the Data Source of a connection string to be a file within my application folder?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, connection-string

I am creating an application that needs a database as it's data store. I have installed `SQLite` in my project (including `Entity Framework 6.0.0`) as well as the extension `SQLite Server Compact ToolBox`.

I am trying to create a database in a local file using `SQLite` but I'm unsure of the format for doing so in the `Data Source` part of the `connection string`. This is using a code first approach.

I have looked at 20+ videos and read numerous tutorials online about how to set up databases using `Entity Framework` over the past couple of months and still am lost about how to set up and run a database from code. I can create the `Models` and the `Context`, perform `CRUD` operations on a database I have created somewhere in my program files (using a default connection string I am guessing), but am still none the wiser about where they are installed and `connection strings`, specifically `Data Source`, I want the database to be shipped with the application not requiring a separate install.

Every time I come back to adding a database to my Application I have got frustrated at the lack of clear tutorials on this subject, including one I paid for! So I leave it till later, but it is the last hurdle in my Application so now is 'later'.

Any help would be appreciated!

TLDR: I need to know what the syntax/format is for a `Connection Strings` `Data Source` targeting a folder/file within my project using `SQLite`.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create connection string simply write

> Data Source=NewApp.db

and that's all